# How to deploy with sequelize and react in heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, environment-variables

This is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "aracelli-v-photography-website",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "private": true,
  "description": "a photography website",
  "main": "api/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently -p \"{name}\" -c \"green\" -n \"database,node\" \"npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --env=production\" \"HOSTING_DIR=livebuild/ node server\"",
    "dev": "concurrently -p \"{time}-{name}\" -c \"green\" -n \"react,nodemon\" \"react-scripts build\" \"nodemon server\"",
    "test": "concurrently -p \"{time}-{name}\" -c \"green\" -n \"database,node\" \"DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a aracelli-v-photography) npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --env=production\" \"DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a aracelli-v-photography) node server\"",
    "build": "BASE_URL=\"https://aracelli-v-photography.herokuapp.com/api\" react-scripts build && rm -rf livebuild && mv build livebuild"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Aracelli-V-Photography/aracelli-v-photography-website.git"
  },
  "author": "jadelynnmasker",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Aracelli-V-Photography/aracelli-v-photography-website/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "njwt": "^1.1.0",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }My question is, why doesn't the server deploy with react
}
```

And my `server.js`:

```js
const http = require("http");
const url = require("url");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const routes = require("./config/routes");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const HOME_DIRECTORY = process.cwd();
const STATIC_DIRECTORY = process.env.HOSTING_DIR || "build/";

const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    try {
        process.chdir(HOME_DIRECTORY);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    if (request.url.split("/")[1] !== "api") {
        const parsedUrl = url.parse(request.url);
        let pathname = `.${parsedUrl.pathname}`;
        const extension = path.parse(pathname).ext;

        try {
            process.chdir(STATIC_DIRECTORY);
        } catch (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }

        const mapExtensionsToContentType = {
            ".ico": "image/x-icon",
            ".html": "text/html",
            ".js": "text/javascript",
            ".json": "application/json",
            ".css": "text/css",
            ".png": "image/png",
            ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
            ".wav": "audio/wav",
            ".mp3": "audio/mpeg",
            ".svg": "image/svg+xml",
            ".pdf": "application/pdf",
            ".doc": "application/msword",
        };

        fs.exists(pathname, function (exist) {
            if (!exist) {
                response.statusCode = 301;
                response.setHeader("Location", "/");
                return response.end(() => {
                    console.log(
                        "\nUser probably refreshed the page. Stand by for new session!"
                    );
                });
            }

            if (pathname === "./") {
                pathname += "index.html";
                console.log("\nUser joined the site!");
            }

            fs.readFile(pathname, function (error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    response.statsCode = 500;
                    response.end(`Error getting the file: ${error}`);
                    return console.error(`Error getting the file: ${error}`);
                }
                response.setHeader(
                    "Content-Type",
                    mapExtensionsToContentType[extension] || "text/html"
                );
                response.end(data);
            });
        });
    } else {
        const actionPath = `${request.method} ${request.url}`;
        const route = routes.find(function (route) {
            return actionPath.match(route[0]);
        });
        if (!route) {
            return console.log(`\n${actionPath} -> undefined`);
        }
        console.log(`\n${actionPath} -> ${route[1]}`);
        const [controllerName, method] = route[1].split("#");
        const Controller = require(`./controllers/${controllerName}Controller`);
        if (request.method !== "POST") {
            const controller = new Controller(request, response);
            controller[method]();
        } else {
            let body = "";
            request.on("data", function (chunk) {
                body += chunk.toString();
            });
            request.on("end", function () {
                controller = new Controller(
                    request,
                    response,
                    JSON.parse(body)
                );
                controller[method]();
            });
        }
    }
});

server.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Server running on port " + PORT);
});
```

Finally, my `/src/redux/common.js`, where I think the problem is:

```js
import axiosBase from "axios";
import { v4 as uuidv4, v5 as uuidv5 } from "uuid";

export const axios = axiosBase.create({
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3000/api",
});

const NAMESPACE = uuidv4();

export function uuid() {
  return uuidv5(uuidv4(), NAMESPACE);
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to host a Node.js server with more knowledge in React than in Node, and I'm stuck here because no matter what I do axios always sends requests to "http://localhost:3000/api". I need to deploy on heroku and have it send requests to heroku instead of my local machine! I looked at the docs for create-react-app and it looks like I am doing it right. I am, however, always using a production build of react because I couldn't figure out where to find the development build. Because of how it's deployed on heroku (my node server serves the react app as well as the api) I don't want my app running on two different ports and needing cors.

With that out of the way, there are basically two solutions to my problem that will make me happy. One is, I could find where the development build is and use the NODE_ENV enviromnent variable to determine whether I am on a server or not. Or, two, I could find a way to make the enviroment variables that I am using work.

Either way, I appreciate your time and consideration. If more information is needed, I will gladly post an update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your app bro. You have made an error in your `package.json`. What you have done is include your `dependencies` in the `devDependencies` which means that react module is not being installed on your Heroku app.

During the deployment, you will notice that it shows a line `pruning devDependencies` which means that it's cutting the packages from the list which are in the `devDependencies`.

#### Steps to make things right:

*You have to include your `devDependencies` in `dependencies`*
To do so run this command

```
npm install axios react react-dom react-redux 
react-router-dom react-scripts redux redux-devtools-extension redux-thunk uuid --save-prod
```

Now push your app to Heroku and it will start working.

[image]